# Polkadot-JS Import BIP44 Address w/Derivation?

Tags: polkadot, polkadot-js

SafePal S1 uses the following derivation path according to their website for Polkadot:

m/44h/354h/0h

SafePal is using BIP39/44 mnemonic phrase standard. I am trying to import my mnemonic phrase into the Polkadot-JS Chrome Extension but have no reference as to what to use for the derivation path since. Can anyone help here?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [wiki on derivation paths](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/en/learn-accounts#derivation-paths) - you likely will want to explore `subkey` for more details (linked there)

And just above in the page, referencing [substrate's BIP39](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-bip39) protocol.